# Communication between Flask and Bokeh containers created using docker-compose fails with ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Tags: python, docker, flask, docker-compose, bokeh

I'm currently getting into Bokeh and experimented a bit with making a Bokeh server available in a network using Docker, which went pretty good so far. Originally I used Bokeh's FileInput widget to upload csv files to the Bokeh server as data source but that becomes rather cumbersome if you want to upload more than a few files. So I scrapped Bokeh's FileInput and tried to build a html template with Flask where I can select and upload multiple files at once. After fiddling a bit with JavaScript to transfer the files to the Bokeh server I finally got that running too. Then I tried again to containerize the whole thing and managed to do so by running both Bokeh and Flask in containers manually and hard-coding the IP of the Bokeh server in the Flask file.

This is far from optimal, since IPs could change or if I build a different Bokeh app I'd have to set up everything manually again. So I tried to use docker-compose to take care of that for me and that's where I hit a major wall. I absolutely can't get the Flask container to communicate with the Bokeh container. They're both running and I can access them separately but the Bokeh server won't be embedded in Flask's html and I always get `net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` in the console.

I've got two ideas what the problem's origin could be but right now I don't know how to solve either of them.

**1. I'm trying to call the Bokeh container in a wrong way**

or

**2. The Bokeh server can't be embedded this way when using docker-compose**

Here are the essential parts of the code:

The bokeh server is run as `bokeh serve bkapp.py --allow-websocket-origin=*` .

The docker-compose.yaml looks like this:

```
version: '3'

services:
    flaskapp:
        container_name: composed-flask
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: flaskapp.Dockerfile
        volumes:
            - './:/app'
        ports:
            - '14100:8000'
    bokehapp:
        container_name: composed-bokeh
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: bokehapp.Dockerfile
        ports:
            - '5006:5006'
        volumes:
            - './:/app'
```

The respective ports are also `EXPOSE`d in the corresponding dockerfile.

In the flask file a piece of JavaScript Code is generated with Bokeh's `server_document`, which is then inserted in the html template.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from bokeh.embed import server_document

app = Flask(__name__)

# Index page, no args
@app.route('/')
def bkapp_page():
    script = server_document('http://bokehapp:5006/bkapp')
    return render_template("fileupload.html", script=script, template="Flask")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000, debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

I also tried to use the container name `composed-bokeh` and `0.0.0.0` instead of the service name without success.

Is it possible to embed a containerized Bokeh server into Flask this way or do I have to change it entirely?

Comment: What's actually launching the Flask application?  (Is it the default `CMD` in a Dockerfile, for example?)  Is the Bokeh backend correctly listening on 0.0.0.0:5006?  ...or are you getting the error in a browser, running outside of Docker, that's gotten a hold of that URL via the `server_document()` call?

Comment: The Flask application is launched as you guessed by the Dockerfile using `ENTRYPOINT ["python", "/app/flask/flask_multifile.py"]`. I can access the Bokeh server from the browser since it's port 5006 is also exposed to the outside. But when I open port 14100 in the browser where Flask is running I only see the html template and the JavaScript code which should embed the Bokeh server fails with: `GET http://bokehapp:5006/bkapp/autoload.js?bokeh-autoload-element=1002&bokeh-app-path=/bkapp&bokeh-absolute-url=http://bokehapp:5006/bkapp net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

Comment: Browser applications never get to use the Docker-internal host names.  You’ll need to configure what gets sent to the browser with the host’s host name and the published port.

Comment: @DavidMaze : Okay, I also thought that maybe the JavaScript code to embed the Bokeh server is only executed when the Flask site is called in the browser and the browser obviously doesn't know about the host names in the internal Docker network. This means my guess #2 was right: I can't embed the Bokeh server in this way. So how do I do it instead? How can I configure what is sent to the browser? Do I have to build something around the Flask and Bokeh containers? I've seen something like nginx and gunicorn mentioned before but I have no experience with any of those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As David Maze [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60384654/communication-between-flask-and-bokeh-containers-created-using-docker-compose-fa#comment106845517_60384654), the problem is that the embedding of the Bokeh server happens only on client side and therefore it must be reachable from the outside. In the end I used an .env file where I put the IP of the host and the Bokeh server's port, so I have to change the values only in one place.

Now I've learned that Bokeh supports the upload of multiple files inherently since a recent update. So this whole setup became rather pointless and can be achieved a lot easier now.